# Is there a resnet50_v2 pretrained on imageNet for Pytorch?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, resnet, imagenet

I'm new to ML, and as the title states, I'm wondering if there's a pretrained ResNet50_v2 with ImageNet on PyTorch?

I looked at https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/models.html
and found torchvision.models.resnet50(..) but I don't think that's the same as ResNet50_v2?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official position is that it will **not** be added, as you can see [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/issues/154#issuecomment-782881168):

> [fmassa](https://github.com/fmassa): "*We've added ResNeXt to torchvision, but ResNetv2 didn't really caught up with the community so we won't be adding it*"